# define multiple mongos instances in a spring data mongodb project

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

we have a HA deployment of mongodb including multiple shards and 2 mongos nodes. all access to the underlying mongod instances is done via these mongos nodes.
my question is if there is a possibility to configure these 2 mongos instances so spring-data-mongodb will either load balance between them or at least try to connect the second one i the first is not available

Thanks,

Uzi

Comment: You don't really want to do that. You want to use something like consul or kubernetes (or any other similar tool) to give you dns access to an appropriate service. You're trying to do too much in your code -- this is an infrastructure concern.